# Synergy connection timeout (Mac client, Windows 10 server)

Tags: virtualbox, ip-address

*[Apologies for posting a non-programming topic, but I thought this post would help others in need.]*

I'm trying to get synergy working between a PC and a Mac.

I'm using auto-config, and all the default settings. It works perfectly with the mac as the server.

However, when the PC is the server and the mac as client, the PC first detects a zeroconf client, but then just sits there with no more log messages. Meanwhile, the mac client keeps "timing out" and never connects.

Things I've checked:

- Windows Firewall is correctly configured to let synergy run - there
  are rules allowing TCP and UDP connections for the synergy
  executables
- I've tried both 32 bit and 64 bit synergy versions
- I've tried auto-config client, and also tried using the screen name and
  the IP address.
- I've tried running with elevated permissions
- I can PING each machine from the other using the terminal - we are
  connected to the same Wi-Fi network!

I have a Macbook (10.11) called Ian-Mac.local, with IP address 192.168.0.6.

I have a Windows 10 Laptop called Ian-PC with 5 different IP addresses listed. The default one is 192.168.56.1

Here's the debug-level log from the PC:

```
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] NOTE: started server, waiting for clients
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: event queue is ready
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: add pending events to buffer
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: screen "Ian-PC" shape changed
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: accepted ipc client connection
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: start ipc handle data
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: ipc read: IHEL
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: finished ipc handle data
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] DEBUG: ipc hello, type=node
[2016-12-06T12:04:49] INFO: watchdog status: ok
[2016-12-06T12:04:50] DEBUG: started process, session=1, elevated: yes, command="C:/Program Files (x86)/Synergy/synergys.exe" -f --no-tray --debug DEBUG --name Ian-PC --ipc --enable-drag-drop --profile-dir "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local" -c "C:/Users/Ian/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.ZU7304" --address :24800 --serial-key MY_LICENCE_KEY --res-w 1920 --res-h 1080 --prm-wc 960 --prm-hc 540
[2016-12-06T12:04:55] INFO: zeroconf client detected: Ian-Mac.local
```

Here's the debug-level log from the mac:

```
2016-12-06T12:12:02] INFO: starting client
[2016-12-06T12:12:02] INFO: command: /Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/synergyc -f --no-tray --debug DEBUG --name Ian-Mac.local --enable-drag-drop 192.168.56.1:24800
[2016-12-06T12:12:02] INFO: config file: /var/folders/k3/rzjn4xxj5tz3j1ygq72cwyj00000gp/T/Synergy.txK899
[2016-12-06T12:12:02] INFO: log level: DEBUG
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] INFO: drag and drop enabled
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: screen shape: center=0,0 size=1920x1080 on 1 display
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: starting watchSystemPowerThread
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: adopting new buffer
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: opened display
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] NOTE: started client
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] NOTE: connecting to '192.168.56.1': 192.168.56.1:24800
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: waiting for carbon loop
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: started watchSystemPowerThread
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: waiting for event loop
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: event queue is ready
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: signalling carbon loop ready
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: add pending events to buffer
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: starting carbon loop
[2016-12-06T12:12:03] DEBUG: carbon loop ready
2016-12-06 12:12:03.091 synergyc[1059:39119] starting cocoa loop
[2016-12-06T12:12:18] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out
[2016-12-06T12:12:18] DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
[2016-12-06T12:12:19] NOTE: connecting to '192.168.56.1': 192.168.56.1:24800
[2016-12-06T12:12:34] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out
[2016-12-06T12:12:34] DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Synergy picked up the wrong IP address!**

> I have a Windows 10 Laptop called Ian-PC with 5 different IP addresses
>   listed. The default one is 192.168.56.1

Running `IPCONFIG` on the windows machine showed that the IP address picked up by synergy was for my "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network". The issue was due to my installation of "Virtual Box".

Instead of using the default IP, I entered the one listed by `IPCONFIG` as "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi", which was 192.168.0.4

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem.

Comment: solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues with Barrier. Which is a fork of Synergy Core and Open Sourced.

So I'm posting how I resolved it. It might help somebody.
I had the same issues. After an hour of searching Internet, I got it working.

1. Barrier was picking up the wrong IP Address which was my Ethernet IP Address. Thanks to [Ians Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40995643/8885198)

[image]

So make sure you run `ipconfig` on the server, in my case, it's **Windows 10**
and see the correct IP Address Under **Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi** IPV4 address.

[image]

2. Make sure you give the same **Screen Name**

In my case, the name is **mac** (Windows 10 Screenshot)

[image]

Mac OS Screenshot

[image]

I had problems if my Wifi is set to password-protected (which is just my mobile hotspot). So to get around that I made it public and limited the connections to it.

That's it. I hope it helps somebody :)

Comment: I named my macbook "name" and tried to connect to a server named "Name", didn't think it was case insensitive, changed names entirely and voila, thanks for the answer was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well - but actually I was attempting to connect an iMac to a MacBook Pro running Win10 via Bootcamp (so basically the same problem).  When I ran ipconfig and obtained the IP address for my wifi adapter, everything connected perfectly.

Thanks for giving me back the rest of my evening.